# Keeping PowerShell Open after CTRL-BREAK

Tags: powershell

I am working with Python Django in Windows Vista Powershell. After I run `python manage.py runserver` ,
it asks me to `CTRL-BREAK` to stop the process. But after I typed that, Powershell stops the process and 
closes. Is there a way to stop the process and keep the Powershell open?

Comment: This django-windows default is terrible for lots of reasons (like the fact that many laptops and even the built-in virtual keyboard don't have a break key). I wish I could find a work-around.

Comment: Python often lies about what to do to exit/stop a process. But you can try other CTRL-<options>. For example: CTRL-C/Z/D

Comment: @user1147688 ctrl+break instantly kills the python interpreter on windows while ctrl+c can be catched or ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the PowerShell console host uses `Ctrl+C` to terminate an ongoing operation and `Ctrl+Break` terminates the operation AND closes the host session. It's a most unfortunate choice IMHO but it's there and we get to live with it.

I find the easiest thing to do when I run into situations like this is from the PowerShell session simply execute `cmd` from the PowerShell prompt. Now I'm actually bypassing PowerShell temporarily and I'm easily back to my PowerShell session when done.

The other thing you should probably consider is using **cmd.exe** rather than PowerShell unless there is some feature of PowerShell you're trying to leverage.

Answer (score 1):

You may try it in this way:

1. Your powershell launches your python program in a job
2. Trap Ctrl-C by the powershell main process
3. When Ctrl-C is trapped, stop the job launched in step 1

Then, you can keep your powershell script continuing

1. To launch a background job, use [start-job](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849698.aspx)

   $killMe = start-job -scriptblock {&python manage.py}
2. To trap Ctrl-C, tell your console to treat Ctrl-C as an input, check [this from MSTN](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/fb409048-a607-4895-8ab3-08c2ec656c7a/trapping-ctrlc-in-powershell-v2?forum=winserverpowershell).

   [console]::TreatControlCAsInput = $true

Then run an UI loop for checking keys input:

```
while ($true) {

  write-host "Processing..."
  if ([console]::KeyAvailable) {

    $key = [system.console]::readkey($true)
    if (($key.modifiers -band [consolemodifiers]"control") -and
      ($key.key -eq "C")) {

      :
      break
    }
  }
}
:
```

3. To stop the job when the "Ctrl-C" is hit,

   stop-job -job $killMe

However, life will not be easy if you need to interact with your python server, which is running at the background. And you would probably like to display your server's output constantly.